# How theses two codes with the same structure generate two different outcomes?

Tags: python, generator, typeerror

I have two codes with the same structure but different task. One of them generates the correct answer but the other generates a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'

```
# The correct one
def square_digits(num):
    return int(''.join(str(int(i)**2) for i in str(num)))

# The one generates Type error
def mirror(num):
    return int(''.join(str(num)[i]) for i in range(len(str(num))-1,-1,-1))
```

Comment: Wrong placement of parentheses…? The second one is `int(''.join(...) for ...)`, which is clearly trying to work on a generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way your functions are written might be confusing and unclear. This might also prevent you from realizing where the error comes from, so I took your code and turned

```
def square_digits(num):
    return int(''.join(str(int(i)**2) for i in str(num)))

# The one generates Type error
def mirror(num):
    return int(''.join(str(num)[i]) for i in range(len(str(num))-1,-1,-1))
```

into equivalent code but I replaced the generator object with a regular `for` loop:

```
def square_digits(num):
    result = []
    for i in str(num):
        result += [str(int(i)**2)]
    result = ''.join(result)
    result = int(result)
    return result

# The one generates Type error
def mirror(num):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(str(num))-1,-1,-1):
        result += [''.join(str(num)[i])]
    result = int(result)
    return result
```

Since the code itself is equivalent, `mirror` still produces the same error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
>     print(mirror(12))
>   File "test.py", line 22, in mirror
>     result = int(result)
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
> ```

When you call

```
result = int(result)
```

inside the `mirror` function, `result` is still a list. That's where the error comes from.

When you look at this unraveled code, is this still what you wanted to write or do you spot the mistake in your algorithm?

Comment: Thanks @Jayjayyy
I turned the code to this and it Worked:

def mirror(num):
    return int(''.join((str(num)[i]) for i in range(len(str(num))-1,-1,-1)))

It needs a parenthesis Thanks again.